# Hibernate Envers in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, hibernate-envers

I would like to use Hibernate Envers in my Grails (v3.0.11) application. Since the grails envers plugins are dead, I tried to do it on my own.

What I did:

in build.gradle, I added the Hibernate Envers dependency
`compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers"`

My domain looks like:

```
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited

@Audited
class Hotel {
    String name
}
```

in the scaffolded Controller, I only changed:

```
class HotelController {

    ...

    @Transactional
    def save(Hotel hotel) {
        ...
        Hotel.withTransaction {
            hotel.save flush:true    
        }
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

I get the following exception when saving:

```
URI
    /hotel/save
Class
    org.hibernate.envers.exception.AuditException
Message
    null
Caused by
    Unable to create revision because of non-active transaction

    Line | Method
->> 1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by HibernateSystemException: Unable to create revision because of non-active transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.envers.exception.AuditException: Unable to create revision because of non-active transaction
->>   32 | doCall    in HotelController.groovy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     96 | doInTransaction in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
|     93 | execute . in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate
|     31 | $tt__save in HotelController.groovy
|     96 | doInTransaction in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
|     93 | execute   in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate
|     96 | doInTransaction in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
|     93 | execute   in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by AuditException: Unable to create revision because of non-active transaction
->>   32 | doCall    in HotelController.groovy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     96 | doInTransaction in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
|     93 | execute . in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate
|     31 | $tt__save in HotelController.groovy
|     96 | doInTransaction in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
|     93 | execute   in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate
|     96 | doInTransaction in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
|     93 | execute   in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

What am I doing wrong? How to make the transaction "active" ?

Comment: Looks like you are using two transactions there actually. Try removing the `withTransaction` closure or the `@Transactional` annotation. See what happens with just one transaction in scope.

Comment: I tried both, nothing changed. I was only trying to use the the withTransaction method because I've seen it in the old envers plugin (http://www.lucasward.net/2011/04/grails-envers-plugin.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try excluding the transitive dependencies of envers. worked for me. i guess pulling in `hibernate-entitymanager` does not do any good here. so:

`compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-envers") { transitive = false }`